# How to use select EventEmitter Angular 2 TabstripComponent

Tags: angular, kendo-tabstrip, kendo-ui-angular2

Please let me know the exact syntax for angular 2 tab on select event. I was trying something like as following :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <kendo-tabstrip>
       <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Paris'" (select)="onTabSelected()">
            <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="weather">
                  <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                  <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
            </div>
       </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
       <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'New York'" (select)="onTabSelected()">
            <span class="sunny">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="weather">
                  <h2>29<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                  <p>Sunny weather in New York.</p>
            </div>
       </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
     </kendo-tabstrip>
    `
})
class AppComponent {
  public onTabSelected() {
    console.log('index');
  }
}
```

But it didn't work for me.

Comment: You'll need to look into the documentation for the `kendo-tabstrip-tab` component. This is not a built-in Angular 2 feature. Where did you see info about its `select` event?

Comment: @BeetleJuice select event is part of `kendo-tabstrip` component. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **select EventEmitter** is part of **kendo-tabstrip (TabstripComponent)** and not kendo-tabstrip-tab (TabstripTabComponent)

You can use it like this-

```
<kendo-tabstrip (select)="onTabSelected($event)">
   <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'tab1'" [selected]="true">
        Kendo UI - Tab Strip Demo
   </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
   ....
   ....
```

and in component you can read title like this-

```
 onTabSelected(event: any){
     console.log('Tab Title: ' + event.title);
 }
```

Reference: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/TabstripComponent/

Comment: FYI - June 2018 - I needed to change "(select)" to "(tabSelect)" as per cstewart's answer below, to get it to work. (No doubt Telerik have changed this over time).

Answer (score 2):

The **tabSelect** event of the **TabStripComponent** worked for me.

In the component template:

```
<kendo-tabstrip (tabSelect)="onTabSelected($event)">
   <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'tab1'" [selected]="true">
        Kendo UI - Tab Strip Demo
   </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
   ....
   ....
```

In the component class:

```
onTabSelected(event: any){
     console.log('Tab Title: ' + event.title);
 }
```

Reference: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/TabStripComponent/